# D3 funnel chart.Option value not applied

Tags: d3.js

I have started with creating basic chart using D3 funnel api.

I have provided default width and height options but those are not getting applied. Could anyone please suggest what is the issue.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>

  <title>dc.js Experiment</title>

  <script src='d3.min.js'></script>
  <script src="d3-funnel.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="funnel" >

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
data = [
    ["Grade1",   400],
    ["Grade2", 300],
    ["Grade3",  200],
    ["Grade4",        100]
];
var chart = new D3Funnel("#funnel");
var options = {
                width: 100,   
                height: 50
};
chart.draw(data, options);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options should be like this:

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    width: 100,   
    height: 50
  }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/wtsk2L97/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This worked for me. I wanted to check if there is any API or chart option which will make the last block in funnel as triangle